# iPhone OS4 alarm clock

Tags: iphone, ios4, core-audio

I have read many posts and still i cannot achieve the desired functionality while my application is suspended in the background.
My reference point is [this](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=380271167&mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D6) radio alarm application.

The things i cannot do using local notifications (which are successfully implemented in the radio clock above) are:

1. play alarm sound in the background while phone is muted
2. change phone volume.
3. play mp3 songs.

Also i noticed that they are able to play sounds longer than 30 seconds and even radio as alarm sounds which probably means that local notifications are not being used (audio-wise)

any insight would be appriciated...

Comment: In the Radio Alarm appstore comments, customers complain it drains a lot of battery. That's mean it uses more than local notification. Options are like turning GPS or playing a silent MP3 at background for the whole night kind of thing... just a wild guess.

Comment: were you able to find answer to your question? because i am having the same problem, making a mp3 alarm clock

Answer (score 3):

The reason that this Radio App succeeds in playing a long audio file , is that it actually plays a background silent loop audio while waiting for the alarm .

IMO that's the reason people complain it drains the battery.

Comment: If Apple knew this (which I gather they don't), they would never approve of this app in the first place.

Comment: Hey @Jonny , this answer is very old in iOS terms (applies to ios4, which just introduced multitasking). I guess you should check new apis  if you plan to release a similar app.

Comment: Yes I am thinking of another app that will use an alarm clock feature. But I don't think there are any new APIs for that (or I missed something). The (somewhat crippled) UILocalNotification is likely still the only way to go. I'm not gonna use silent music that will eat peoples' battery...